# What is the established way to request data from an android device

Tags: java, android, web

I currently have an small application that I have been using to learn java/android programming.  Right now I have a setup were the app on one phone sends a request (via sms) to another phone running the same app.  The remote phone receives the request and sends back some info.  Next I would like to try this from the web.  Is there an established "best" way to to this?

I was thinking I would have a web server send requests to the device via google cloud messaging and then have the device return the data directly to the web server.  (Not that I really know how to do any of that just yet).

I see that there is a google cloud messaging return path (send messages from the device to the google cloud server,  but it seems very new,  do I need something like that?  The main thing I want is to be able to ask the phone to do something when I want, not have it poll to see if there is a request, or just periodically update some status.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the answers below for confirming to me that I was on the right track.
I now have some basic functionality.

I started out using this gcm android demo code
https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/#git%2Fgcm-client%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fandroid%2Fgcm%2Fdemo%2Fapp%253Fstate%253Dclosed
and this ruby gem
https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm/blob/master/README.md

between the above two I was able to send a message to my phone pretty easily.

To get the round trip working, I setup a very simple rails app on heroku.
I included a modified version of the sample code in the gcm gem in a controller and then used
HttpPatch (needed for rails 4) to send a post/patch from my phone to my web app, the controller then echoes the message back to my phone.

I guess it would be nice to get the two way gcm stuff to work,  but I am not sure there are any gems that handle that, and I am not qualified to handle a task like that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it's the right call: [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

From the site Android Developer:

> This could be a lightweight message telling your app there is new data
>   to be fetched from the server (for instance, a movie uploaded by a
>   friend), or it could be a message containing up to 4kb of payload data
>   (so apps like instant messaging can consume the message directly).

In this case you don't want to fetch data from the server but you want to send them.

You can send them in different ways. I would suggest, since you are learning, to try a [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) solution using one of the implementation of [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services).

Answer (score 1):

As a short and direct answer for beginner : GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) would solve your issue. However, if your app turned out to be something bigger, other more technical and complicated solutions are present too.

see [this link](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).